# How to determine UIWebView height based on content, within a variable height UITableView?

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiwebview

I am trying to create a `UITableView` with variable height rows as explained in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272584/is-there-a-better-way-to-determine-the-right-size-for-a-uitableviewcell)

My problem is each cell contains a `UIWebView` with different (statically loaded) content I can't figure out how to calculate the proper height based on the content. Is there a way to do this? I've tried things like this:

```
   (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
       WebViewCell *cell = (WebViewCell*)[self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
       [cell setNeedsLayout];
       [cell layoutIfNeeded];
       return cell.bounds.size.height;
    }
```

The cells themselves are loaded from a nib, which is simply a `UITableViewCell` containing a `UIWebView`. (It would also be fine if the cells just adjusted themselves to the largest of the html content, though variable height would be nicer).

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this?  The answers below seem to get you the height, but not until after you need it.  How can you compute the height for heightForRowAtIndexPath is you have to rely on a callback (webview delegate) call in webViewDidFinishLoad?

Comment: Hi then finally how u determine the height of the webview I am also having the same problem...

Comment: Anyone have a solution???? Still cant figure this out..

Answer (score 77):

This code is probably too slow for table view use, but does the trick. It doesn't look like there's any alternative, as UIWebView offers no direct access to the DOM.

In a view controller's `viewDidLoad` I load some HTML in a webview and when the load is finished run some javascript to return the element height.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    webview.delegate = self;
    [webview loadHTMLString:@"<div id='foo' style='background: red'>The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.</div>" baseURL:nil];
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    NSString *output = [webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById(\"foo\").offsetHeight;"];
    NSLog(@"height: %@", output);
}
```

Comment: Sounds like it can be made work, however I've tried this in the table view and it returns an empty string (I guess because the webview had not finished loading). I'm thinking I could precompute this with an offscreen webview perhaps and cache the results for the tableview.

Comment: Are you measuring the height in the webViewDidFinishLoad? That's the delegate callback indicating that load is complete. It shouldn't return an empty string.

Comment: This is almost exactly what I do. Although I am having a problem with the fact that the webview can't return its size until it has finished loading, which it might not have when the table needs to know its size. Does anyone have an idea of how to solve this?

Comment: I used instead:  NSString *output = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.scrollHeight;"];

Comment: With iOS 4.3 I had to do the following : the a tiny height for my webView (ie 1px) and do the call recommended by BadPirate and adjust both the scroll view's content value and the web view's frame value afterwards.

Comment: You must set the height of the initial UIWebView to at least 1px, otherwise when making the JS call you'll get the screen height returned instead.

Answer (score 28):

I was very glad to find your answers, the javascript trick worked well for me.

However, I wanted to say that there is also the "sizeThatFits:" method :

```
CGSize goodSize = [webView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(anyWidth,anyHeigth)];
```

We have to set a preferred size different from zero, but apart from that, it usually always works !

Usually, because with the UIWebViews, it seems to work only on the second loading (I use the "loadHTMLString:" method, and yes I call "sizeThatFits:" from the delegate "didFinishLoad:" method).

So, that's why I was very happy to find your solution which works in any case.

Comment: @Shade: See my answer how to make this work on newer iOS versions.

Comment: BE CAREFUL with this answer! Sometimes it returns wrong `height`! I'm getting wrong value when use it with many images

Answer (score 6):

This seems to work. For now.

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    CGFloat webViewHeight = 0.0f;
    if (self.subviews.count > 0) {
        UIView *scrollerView = [self.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
        if (scrollerView.subviews.count > 0) {
            UIView *webDocView = scrollerView.subviews.lastObject;
            if ([webDocView isKindOfClass:[NSClassFromString(@"UIWebDocumentView") class]])
                webViewHeight = webDocView.frame.size.height;
        }
    }
}
```

It should safely return 0 if it fails.

Comment: How is this better than: [webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById(\"foo\").offsetHeight;"];? The problem is that the webview can't return its size until it has finished loading, which it might not have when the table needs to know its size.

Answer (score 4):

The problem with `-sizeThatFits:` is that it doesn't work out of the box, at least not on iOS 4.1. It just returns the current size of the webView (no matter whether it's called with CGSizeZero or an arbitrary non-zero size).

I found out that it actually works if you reduce the frame height of the webView prior to calling `-sizeThatFits:`.

See my solution: [How to determine the content size of a UIWebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936041/how-to-determine-the-content-size-of-a-uiwebview)

Comment: thank you for the pointer. I did see your solution when I had this problem, but it doesn't work any better in my case. I don't really remember what I needed this for, but I did it in a different way in the end.

Answer (score 4):

The better approach is to use `scrollView.contentSize.height` property, like below.

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
     NSLog(@"%f",webView.scrollView.contentSize.height);   
}
```

Comment: For me, it's scrollView.contentSize.height - CGRectGetHeight(scrollView.frame). http://stackoverflow.com/a/39386880/1677041

Answer (score 3):

If you have bad values with sizeThatFits the first time but not after, here a possible cause I've encountered : a bug with external CSS.
It seems webViewDidFinisLoad is called to soon, before external CSS are retrieved, and the web document fully built.
I think the bug disappears if you reload because of the cache.

A trick : Preload your CSS with a dummy UIWebView soon in your application.

SDK : IOS4

Comment: In my case it was not so much the CSS that was loaded late, but more specifically a font-file in the CSS.

Answer (score 3):

measuring a webview works but only when it has loaded its content

- making webview small (like 5px)
- load it and wait for finish
- calling sizeToFit on it then
- getting the size THEN
- reload the tableview (return the correct height for the cell)

advertisement: :D see my M42WebviewTableViewCell class on github which struggles with this

Comment: That works! Thanks, I used before approach with javascript, but this one works better for me.