# Detecting of scroll bar is visible in the UIWebView

Tags: javascript, iphone, cocoa-touch, uiwebview, mobile-safari

I need to detect if the scroll bar is visible in the UIWebView, how do I do this? My first attempt was:

```
int scrollHeight = [[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.scrollHeight"] intValue];
if(scrollHeight > [webView frame].size.height)
    NSLog(@"Scrollbar is visible");
```

But the `scrollHeight` is always a way larger than the webView height.

Comment: Ask yourself why you need to know when it's visible. This smells as though you're doing something wrong.

Comment: No, there's nothing wrong. It's the client's wish to visually inform the user when he can/should scroll.

Comment: Maybe you could use the [scrollView flashScrollIndicators] method to bling the scrollbars and notify your users that way?

Comment: @Konstantin, Clients often what things they cannot have. Your job is to give them what they ask for of what is possible. UIWebView is not a UIScrollView. Period, full stop.

Comment: This is not always a solution to hard problems

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution is to subclass UIWebView and implement the following:

```
-(void) scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    scrollView.bounces = NO;
}
```

The "shadow" will not be visible anymore, because bouncing is not possible anymore...

Answer (score 0):

Try the following (no private APIs):

```
for (id subView in [webView subviews]) {
    if ([subView respondsToSelector:@selector(flashScrollIndicators)]) {
        [subView flashScrollIndicators];
    }
}
```

This doesn't assume anything about the internal `UIWebView` hierarchy, but just if there happens to be a subview that responds to `flashScrollIndicators` they will be flashed. ;)

Comment: yes, I've seen this before, but I need to create a custom way to visualize this (not by flashScrollIndicators)

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/745160/how-to-determine-uiwebview-height-based-on-content-within-a-variable-height-uita/751326#751326