# how to call method in ios code from html response using uiwebview

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I am consuming html json data in my iOS app. HTML response has few div blocks with onClick methods. When I tap on these blocks I invoke some javascript code in web view, but I need also know about these events in my source code.

For example when I tap on web element and onClick is called I need to invoke some method in the code .

```
- (void)patientResponse:(UIWebView *)webView modeDict:(NSDictionary *)modeDict

- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType 
{
    NSString *protocolPrefix = EVENT;

    NSString *urlStr = [[request URL].absoluteString substringFromIndex:protocolPrefix.length];

    urlStr = [urlStr stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

   NSError *jsonError;        

    NSDictionary *callInfo = [NSJSONSerialization
JSONObjectWithData:[urlStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
options:kNilOptions error:&jsonError];    

    if([[callInfo valueForKey:@"acton"] isEqualToString:Set_id])

    [self patientResponse:webView modeDict:callInfo];

     return NO;  
    }

   - (void)patientResponse:(UIWebView *)webView modeDict:(NSDictionary *)modeDict
    {

    NSString *mode = [[modeDict valueForKey:@"params"] valueForKey:@"PatientName"];

    self.patientName = mode;

    NSLog(@"Patient name is:%@",self.patientName);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Textview insted of UIWebview.
USe attributed string to load html response on textview. 
Hope this help.

Comment: it is not possible. i need to use UIWebview only

Comment: Someone answer for html string into webview you can check following link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7259331/ios-webview-and-string

Comment: Have you got any help?

Comment: can u tell me what u exatly want to do and why textview is not good option, because i used it severl time

Comment: i want to call this method. its enough..    - (void)patientResponse:(UIWebView *)webView modeDict:(NSDictionary *)modeDict

Comment: based on my project requirement

Comment: try to use some wrapper then or EasyJSWebView is also another option,but for this webview need javascript code

Comment: then try to use  EasyJSWebView it will help you
and if it help plz dnt forgot to upvote my ans

Comment: i want to call only this method bro//- (void)patientResponse:(UIWebView *)webView modeDict:(NSDictionary *)modeDict

Comment: http://ramkulkarni.com/blog/calling-objective-c-function-from-javascript-in-ios-applications/ have a look

Comment: bro can u help me based on my code. i mean do u modify my code?