# Text to speech and navigation

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uiscrollview

I'm using the Acapela TTS on iOS.
I have a HTML document with all the text (and markup) that I want read out. 
The text is split in paragraphs and I want to be able to start the TTS at each header.
At the moment I put each paragraph in it's own UIWebView (for handling the internal markup) and add these to a UIScrollView for navigating all the elements. Each UIWebView is overloaded with a button, so when it's pressed, the connected text is read aloud.
My problem now, is that I have to place the UIWebView and Buttons using a frame (meaning a static y-position), but this entails that I have the exact height, which is my current problem.
I have tried using the solutions mentioned in this question: [UIWebView height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/745160/how-to-determine-uiwebview-height-based-on-content-within-a-variable-height-uit), but it still doesn't look good - either the webviews are too high or short, and I need it to be perfect, so it looks like a consistent webpage.

Does anybody know of a different way of doing this type of TTS without splitting it up in separate webviews that I have overlooked?

This is my code that place the UIWebViews:

```
float yOffset = 0;
UIWebView *previous = nil;

//UIWebView delegate
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{

NSString *height = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.scrollHeight;"];

if(previous!=nil){
    yOffset += previous.frame.size.height;
}
CGFloat h = [height floatValue];

CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, yOffset, scrollView.frame.size.width, h); 

[webView setFrame:frame];
[webView setOpaque:NO];
[webView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
previous = webView;
[scrollView addSubview:webView];

yOffset += previous.frame.size.height;

[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width, yOffset)];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea: you could turn the complete paragraphs into clickable links that point to some identifier of the paragraph. Then you can override the clicking event with `UIWebViewDelegate` and get the paragraph text with javascript. I mean something like this:

HTML:

```
<p id="paragraph1"><a href="paragraph1">First paragraph</a></p>
<p id="paragraph2"><a href="paragraph2">Second paragraph</a></p>
```

Implement `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` of `UIWebViewDelegate`:

```
           - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView 
shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request 
            navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType 
{
  NSString* link = [request.URL lastPathComponent]; // not sure

  // use rangeOfString to find all
  if (inType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked && [link compare:@"paragraph1"] == NSOrderedSame) 
  { 
    // check this
    NSString* javaScript = 
      [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementById('%@').nodeValue", link]; 
    NSString paragraphToRead = 
      [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javaScript];
    // read out paragraphToRead
    return NO;
  }
}
```

Comment: Its a sound idea, but the problem is, that I can't change the HTML. It is provided by a company, that does not really have the knowledge to create more specific tags..