# How to get the height of the webpage that got loaded in UIWebView?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, height

I have used following methods but still now not getting the correct value:

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.scrollHeight;"] floatValue]

[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.offsetHeight;"]

webView.scrollView.contentSize.height
```

I have accessed all above in,

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)aWebView 
{

}
```

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/745160/how-to-determine-uiwebview-height-based-on-content-within-a-variable-height-uit) and [this too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936041/how-to-determine-the-content-size-of-a-uiwebview)

Answer (score 2):

You can get this by 2 ways

method 1: Load your html like this

```
embedHTML = [embedHTML stringByAppendingFormat:
               @"<body><div id='size_div'>%@</div></body></html>",yourString];
```

And now in webViewDidFinishLoad method keep this statements...

```
NSString *output = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
                      @"document.getElementById(\"size_div\").offsetHeight;"];  
NSLog(@"height: %@", output);
```

Method 2:

```
UIWebView *objWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
for (UIScrollView *v in objWebView.subviews) {
    if ([v isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]])
    {
        CGSize requiredSize = v.contentSize;
    }
}
```

Comment: Method 1 working fine - In this also some truncation is their i manually adding constant 20 for getting correct height   , but method 2 not working is it any additional thing want to be done for method 2

Comment: where u have added method2 ?

Comment: inside the webViewDidFinishLoad method.

Answer (score 0):

I think `webView.scrollView.contentSize` is set automatically by the webView itself when loading the HTML. Have you tried it exactly like this:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
     float h = [[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.scrollHeight;"] floatValue];

    // h is the height of the loaded webpage...
```

}

And don't forget to set the webView's delegate `YourViewController: UIViewController  <UIWebViewDelegate>`

Comment: Exactly added same thing what you have mentioned above but not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can get webview height by using

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    float height = [[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.scrollHeight;"] floatValue];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

use this

```
let height = webView.scrollView.contetSize.height
```