# WebView height not set based on its content

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I know this question was posted so many times but still I can not change the height of `UIWebView` based on its content

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.title=@"webview";
    [_webView setDelegate:self];

    NSString * string = @"<h1>This is HTML string</h1>";
    [_webView loadHTMLString:string baseURL:nil];
}

- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    return YES;
}


- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    NSLog(@"start loadinng.......");

}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    NSLog(@"finish loading.......");



    CGRect frame = _webView.frame;
    frame.size.height = 1;
    _webView.frame = frame;
    CGSize fittingSize = [_webView sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];
    frame.size = fittingSize;
    _webView.frame = frame;
}

- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Failed to load with error :%@",[error debugDescription]);

}
```

can anybody help me how can resize my `UIWebView` height?

Comment: Why you need to increase the WebView height, it can scroll the content if it is bigger than its height...

Comment: You haven't done anything to change the height of webview.

Comment: @KananVora : thank you for replaying....because i have tableview and each row contain webview and the response of my service is in html string so need to set both cell and webview height based on its content...please help me its very urgent

Comment: @iphonic : is there any solution?? how can i set webview height in tableview's row??

Comment: You can get the height of webview content using this `webview.scrollView.contentSize.height;` in `webViewDidFinishLoad` delegate method..

Comment: @iphonic : i had already tried it but still not able to set webview height. even i followed this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936041/how-to-determine-the-content-size-of-a-uiwebview/3937599#3937599

Comment: @BandishDave : Can't you do it like you just show 1 or 2 lines of your content in the UITableViewCell and on its click, show the full content in the next view. Bcoz the whole content will become very big in terms of a cell.

Comment: @BandishDave The link you posted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936041/how-to-determine-the-content-size-of-a-uiwebview/3937599#3937599 the solution works very fine. See this http://i.imgur.com/JRQq1ko.png

Comment: @iphonic : sir same code i do but don't understand where am going wrong. i just drag webview in my view controll in story board and give its size 0,0,320,150.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer.

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    if (webView.isLoading){
        return;
    }
    CGSize contentSize = webView.scrollView.contentSize;
    NSLog (@"height: %f",contentSize.height);
 }
```

After gettting this height reframe your webView with new width and height and also reframe its parent view if there any.

Comment: i tried this but it returns content size is 504.00 while there is only one line string..so according to my opinion it will be under 50 to 60.can you tell me how can i handle???

Comment: remove [webView sizeToFit] statement first. And also check what size you have given to webView. You should give it minimum size, and then check with one line code. Then also add some more text and then check, it is showing in required height or not.

Comment: i set webview from storyboard in my viewcontroll with the size of 0,0,320,150 default.

Comment: just try with some more data in html.

Answer (score 0):

How about this.

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{

    [webView sizeToFit];
    webView.frame = CGRectMake(x,y,width,webView.frame.size.height);
}
```

Comment: @BandishDave : Did u have delegate for webview? Does webViewDidFinishLoad is getting called?

Comment: :yes sir it is called.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use these methods, to set UIWebview frame as it's content size:

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    CGRect frame = webView.frame;

    frame.size.height = 5.0f;

    webView.frame = frame;
}


- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    CGSize mWebViewTextSize = [webView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(1.0f, 1.0f)];  // Pass about any size

    CGRect mWebViewFrame = webView.frame;


    mWebViewFrame.size.height = mWebViewTextSize.height;

    webView.frame = mWebViewFrame;


    //Disable bouncing in webview
    for (id subview in webView.subviews)
    {
        if ([[subview class] isSubclassOfClass: [UIScrollView class]])
        {
            [subview setBounces:NO];
        }
    }
}
```

They are automatically called (if you set webviews delegate to this class), when WebView has finished loading it's content.

or

1. [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/745160/how-to-determine-uiwebview-height-based-on-content-within-a-variable-height-uit)
2. [raywenderlich-tutorial](http://raywenderlich.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=6095)

This might helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
First calculate height of web view for desired content.
NSString* lString = @"<h1>This is HTML string</h1>";
NSAttributedString* lAttributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData: [lString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
options:@{ 
NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType,
NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: @(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
}                                                               
documentAttributes: nil 
error:nil];

CGRect lBoundingRect = [lAttributedText boundingRectWithSize: CGSizeMake(_webView.bounds.size.width, CGFLOAT_MAX) options: NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading context: nil];

then set it to _webView.frame

Now, load web view
[_webView setDelegate:self];

[_webView loadHTMLString: lString baseURL:nil];
```